# Can the ALT tag impact on whether the image shows up or not?

Tags: php, html

I'm building 3 email marketing sent by PHP.

The important piece of HTML code to look at is the following:

More specifically the **ALT** value.

```
<img align="top" alt="Header" src="@domain@/img/marketing/all_logo.png" style="width: 76px; height: 68px;"/>    
<img align="top" alt="Multz" src="@domain@/img/marketing/all_logo.png" style="width: 76px; height: 68px;"/>    
<img align="top" alt="Header" src="@domain@/img/marketing/all_logo.png" style="width: 76px; height: 68px;"/>
```

*Those 3 lines of codes comes from 3 different files.*

A PHP file loads them into a variable and shoots them as email to a given email address. It only fixes the **@domain@** value.

During my tests, I noticed that only 1 of the emails would show the image properly and the only difference is the ALT tag. 

When I changed the ALT tag from the others, it worked.

Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: I managed to figure out that the problem is with the word "header" only, though I still don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for having an alt tag is to have text replace the image in the case it fails to load. It shouldn't affect whether the image shows up or not - when I replaced your source image with a placeholder URL, everything seemed to be working fine:

```
<img align="top" alt="Header" src="http://placehold.it/76x68" style="width: 76px; height: 68px;"/>    
<img align="top" alt="Multz" src="http://placehold.it/76x68" style="width: 76px; height: 68px;"/>    
<img align="top" alt="Header" src="http://placehold.it/76x68" style="width: 76px; height: 68px;"/>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wj7j7kpb/)